# Export/Rasterize alpha shape to bitmap

Tags: matlab, bitmap, export, shapes, rasterize

I build an alpha shape from some points (example given in code) and want to export the shape to a raster graphics format. I need the shape only, not the plot markings (axis, scales ect).

I need only the resulting triangle on white ground as a bitmap.
Scale needs to be 1 unit = 1 pixel.

```
x = [0 10 20 30 30 30 15];
y = [0 0 0 0 15 30 15];

shape = alphaShape (x',y');

plot (shape, 'FaceColor', 'black');
```

[image: alpha shape plotted]

I have not found anything on how to export shapes or how to rasterize them. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following code after yours.

```
imgwidth = max(1, ceil(max(x) - min(x)));
imgheight = max(1, ceil(max(y) - min(y)));
ax = gca;
ax.Visible = 'off';
ax.XTickMode = 'manual';
ax.YTickMode = 'manual';
ax.ZTickMode = 'manual';
ax.XLimMode = 'manual';
ax.YLimMode = 'manual';
ax.ZLimMode = 'manual';
ax.Position = ax.OuterPosition;
af = gcf;
figpos = getpixelposition(af);
resolution=get(0, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch');
set(af, 'paperunits','inches', ....
    'papersize',[imgwidth imgheight]/resolution, ....
    'paperposition',[0 0 [imgwidth imgheight]/resolution]);
print(af,'out.png','-dpng',['-r',num2str(resolution)],'-opengl')
```

Things done:

- Fetch data range and convert to image dimensions.
- Turn off axes and ticks.
- Minimize/remove padding space surrounding the actual content.
- Map 1 unit in data into 1 pixel in output image.

Things not done:

- Guarantee aspect ratio. (should work, though)

This screenshot shows non-unity aspect ratio output:

[image: example screenshot]

References

[Mathworks - Save Figure at Specific Size and Resolution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-at-specific-size-and-resolution.html)

[MATLAB Central - saving a figure at a set resolution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/287268)

[Mathworks - `print`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html)

[Mathworks - Save Figure with Minimal White Space](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-with-minimal-white-space.html)